# mail.app crasches on startup, OS 10.5.8

Tags: macos, apple-mail

The mail.app (3.6) crashes on launch -- or rather, it doesn't launch. The report says:

> Process:         Mail [282] Path:
>   /Applications/Mail.app/Contents/MacOS/Mail
>   Identifier:      com.apple.mail
>   Version:         ??? (???) Build Info:
>   Mail-9360000~1 Code Type:       PPC
>   (Native) Parent Process:  launchd
>   [103]
>
> Interval Since Last Report:
>   3170 sec Crashes Since Last Report:
>   1 Per-App Interval Since Last Report: 
>   0 sec Per-App Crashes Since Last
>   Report:   1
>
> Date/Time:       2010-01-24
>   01:38:35.221 +0100 OS Version:
>   Mac OS X 10.5.8 (9L31a) Report
>   Version:  6 Anonymous UUID: 
>   8323A671-FCB6-4393-A60E-F633543786FF
>
> Exception Type:  EXC_BREAKPOINT
>   (SIGTRAP) Exception Codes:
>   0x0000000000000001, 0x000000008fe0105c
>   Crashed Thread:  0
>
> Dyld Error Message:   Symbol not
>   found: __NSConcreteStackBlock
>   Referenced from:
>   /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/iLifeMediaBrowser.framework/Versions/A/iLifeMediaBrowser
>   Expected in:
>   /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib

The system.log says (don't know if it's related; there are sevral passages like this one):

> Jan 24 01:21:52
>   carl-henrik-fredrikssons-imac-g5
>   com.apple.dyld[266]:
>   update_dyld_shared_cache[266] for
>   arch=ppc failed: could not resolve
>   _DASessionSetDispatchQueue from /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/iLifeMediaBrowser.framework/Versions/A/iLifeMediaBrowser
>   in
>   /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/iLifeMediaBrowser.framework/Versions/A/iLifeMediaBrowser
>   Jan 24 01:21:54
>   carl-henrik-fredrikssons-imac-g5
>   com.apple.dyld[266]:
>   update_dyld_shared_cache[266] for
>   arch=ppc failed: read failure copying
>   dylib. Read of 4816896 bytes at file
>   offset 45056 returned 222592 for
>   /System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/Versions/A/Resources/libCGATS.A.dylib
>   while copying
>   /System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/Versions/A/Resources/libCGATS.A.dylib
>   to shared cache

There's only one Mail.app on the computer.

I have two users on my machine (iMac G5, iSight, Mac OS 10.5.8). Same problem with both users. I have tried to delete all mail-related files in the library (e.g. Mail folder and com.apple.mail.plist).

I have also repaired permissions and installed the combo update of 10.5.8.

Before I started the Mail.app for the first time, I migrated programs and one user profile from another mac (MacBook Pro running Snow Leopard). I guess this might have caused the problem.

I don't have a Leopard system disc (the OS was installed on the hard drive when I had to have it (the hard drive) replaced by an official Apple shop. I don't know what more to try...

Comment: Please read the FAQ. This is not a forum. To update your question please edit the original and add aditional information. Also don't post an answer to respond to someone, add a comment to their answer. Only answer if you have the solution to the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Migrating *from* Snow Leopard may well be your problem. Snow Leopard only runs on Intel machines and the majority of it's applications and frameworks are not ["universal" binaries](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_binary).

Most likely, the Snow Leopard apps you migrated across to Leopard were built with Snow Leopard-specific features only and can't be run on any OS version before Snow Leopard.

The `update_dyld_shared_cache` errors you've got might be caused by the migration of some programs from Snow Leopard. If you boot into safe mode this dynamic library cache gets deleted and *might* solve your problem. Basically - hold down 'shift' when the grey screen with the Apple logo appears at boot.

Check out http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1455 and the links from there to learn about safe mode.

Which programs did you migrate?  Because you *may* have some Intel-only binaries on your G5 now I don't know what other problems lie in store.